# Pass data in np.dnarray to Highcharts

Tags: python, numpy, highcharts, flask, jinja2

I'm working with python 2.7, jinja2, flask and Highcharts. I create two numpy array (`x1 and x2, type = numpy.dnarray`) and I pass to Highcharts. My problems is, Highcharts don't recognize the commas in the vector.

This is my jinja2 code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

      series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: {{ x1 }}
        },  {
            name: 'London',
            data: {{ x2 }}
        }]
    });
});
```

And this is the error that I look with `network chrome dev tools`:

```
series: [{
     name: 'Tokyo',
     data: [1 4 5 2 3]
},  {
     name: 'London',
     data: [3 6 7 4 1]
}]
```

I need change the numpy array to python list to pass to Highcharts or there is a better way to do?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that changing it to a list is probably the fastest/easiest route.  you could do it in your template like this:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

      series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: {{ x1.tolist() }}
        },  {
            name: 'London',
            data: {{ x2.tolist() }}
        }]
    });
});
```

Or you could do the conversion before you pass it to jinja...

```
template.render(x1=numpy_array.tolist(), x2=numpy_array.to_list())
```

There's not much of a difference really -- mostly just your (or your project's) preference.

Of course, you *could* go through all the shenanigans of creating a custom filter and using that in the template:  `{{ x2 | repr_as_list }}` which could avoid some data copying, but that's probably more work than it's worth.  (It *might* save a tiny bit of memory but is likely to perform slower and be more work to implement)

Answer (score 0):

The problems is Highcharts only accepts `list` and not `numpy.array`. So, if I like pass x array I only do `template.render(x1 = list(x))`.